# Right justify header test using TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

This first image shows the standard header layout when using TCPDF:

[image]

What I would like to do is right justify the text, as shown below, but I have not been able to figure out how to do this:

[image]

Please offer some suggestions! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is with the `writeHTMLCell()` method. Setting the `$w` parameter to 0 will cause the cell to extend to the right margin. The `$align` parameter can then be set to `'R'`, which will right-align the cell content.

### Example

```php
$html = '<strong>Header Title</strong><br/>
         Header string, Line 1<br/>
         Header string, Line 2<br/>
         Header string, Line 3';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(
    $w=0,
    $h=0,
    $x=0,
    $y=10,
    $html,
    $border=0,
    $ln=0,
    $fill=false,
    $reseth=true,
    $align='R'
);
```

### Working Example

This full example can be run in the TCPDF examples directory.

```php
<?php
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
class MYPDF extends TCPDF
{
    public function Header()
    {
        $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo_example.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG');
        $html = '<strong>Header Title</strong><br/>
                 Header string, Line 1<br/>
                 Header string, Line 2<br/>
                 Header string, Line 3';
        $this->writeHTMLCell(
            $w=0,
            $h=0,
            $x=0,
            $y=10,
            $html,
            $border=0,
            $ln=0,
            $fill=false,
            $reseth=true,
            $align='R'
        );
    }
}

$pdf = new MYPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Adam - thank you. Needless to say, I had to tweak the logo size/offset, but this worked like a charm.